# Failed to build IOS app and stuck permanently on terminal

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, unity-game-engine

```
oui-MacBookPro example % flutter build ios --debug
Running "flutter pub get" in example...
Resolving dependencies... (3.5s)
  _flutterfire_internals 1.0.2 (1.3.1 available)
  async 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)
  basic_utils 4.5.2 (5.5.4 available)
  characters 1.2.1 (1.3.0 available)
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface 5.7.7 (5.14.1 available)
  cloud_firestore_web 2.8.10 (3.5.1 available)
  collection 1.17.0 (1.17.2 available)
  disposables 0.1.2 (1.0.0 available)
  file 6.1.4 (7.0.0 available)
  firebase_auth 3.11.2 (4.6.1 available)
  firebase_auth_platform_interface 6.10.1 (6.15.1 available)
  firebase_auth_web 4.6.1 (5.5.1 available)
  firebase_core 1.24.0 (2.13.0 available)
  firebase_core_platform_interface 4.5.1 (4.8.0 available)
  firebase_core_web 1.7.3 (2.5.0 available)
  firebase_database 9.1.7 (10.2.1 available)
  firebase_database_platform_interface 0.2.2+7 (0.2.5+1 available)
  firebase_database_web 0.2.1+9 (0.2.3+1 available)
  firebase_storage 10.3.11 (11.2.1 available)
  firebase_storage_platform_interface 4.1.19 (4.4.1 available)
  firebase_storage_web 3.3.9 (3.6.1 available)
  fl_chart 0.61.0 (0.62.0 available)
  flutter_ffmpeg 0.4.2 (discontinued)
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.14 (2.0.15 available)
  intl 0.17.0 (0.18.1 available)
  js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
  matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.16 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.5.0 available)
  meta 1.8.0 (1.9.1 available)
  path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
  petitparser 5.1.0 (5.4.0 available)
  quiver 2.1.5 (3.2.1 available)
  source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
  table_calendar 3.0.8 (3.0.9 available)
  test_api 0.4.16 (0.6.0 available)
  win32 4.1.4 (5.0.2 available)
  xml 6.2.2 (6.3.0 available)
Got dependencies!
Building com.xraph.plugin.fuwPluginExample for device (ios)...
Warning: Missing build name (CFBundleShortVersionString).
Warning: Missing build number (CFBundleVersion).
Action Required: You must set a build name and number in the pubspec.yaml file
version field before submitting to the App Store.
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in
Xcode project: LQG34PYSWH
Running pod install...                                              4.7s
Upgrading Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           28.9s
Failed to build iOS app
```

what maybe the problem?
M1 Macbook pro.
deleting plugin from pub spec.yaml file dosen't work neither
flutter doctor is as below.

Flutter version 3.7.11 on channel stable at /Users/pedrojung/Downloads/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision f72efea43c (6 weeks ago), 2023-04-11 11:57:21 -0700
• Engine revision 1a65d409c7
• Dart version 2.19.6
• DevTools version 2.20.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/pedrojung/Library/Android/sdk
✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
✗ Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14E222b
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

Comment: its says in your build log: You must set a build name and number in the pubspec.yaml file